# All components in array.map render to the screen except the last one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a small provider with Context API to show popup on the screen. However, I can not figure out why the last item in my state never render to the screen, even though I can see it when I console.log it in the loop. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

**PopupProvider.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Popup from "../component/Popup/Popup";
import { PopupContextType, PopupProps } from "../type";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const PopupContext = createContext<PopupContextType>([() => {}, () => {}]);
export const usePopup = () => useContext(PopupContext);

function PopupProvider(props: { children: React.ReactChild }) {
  const [popups, setPopups] = useState<PopupProps[]>([]);

  const openPopup = (options: PopupProps) => {
    const popup = { ...options, open: true };
    setPopups((popups) => [...popups, popup]);
  };

  const closePopup = () => {
    setPopups((prevState) => {
      const lastestPopup = prevState.pop();
      return [...prevState];
    });
  };

  const contextValue = useRef([openPopup, closePopup] as const);

  return (
    <PopupContext.Provider value={contextValue.current}>
      {props.children}
      {popups.map((popup, i) => (
          /* console.log(popup) I console.log here and it has the exact numbers of popups. but some how
             the last one never render to the screen */
        <Popup {...popup} key={i} onClose={closePopup}></Popup>
      ))}
    </PopupContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default PopupProvider;
```

**Popup.tsx**

```
function Popup(props: PopupProps) {
  console.log(props);
  const theme = ThemeDict[props.theme || "light"];
  return (
    <div>
      <Overlay
        id="overlay"
        open={props.open}
        theme={theme}
        style={
          props.settings && props.settings["backdropColor"]
            ? { backgroundColor: props.settings["backdropColor"] }
            : {}
        }
        onClick={(e) => {
          if (props.disableBackdropClick) return;
          // @ts-ignore
          if (e.target.id === "overlay") props.onClose();
          else return;
        }}
      >
        <Content
          theme={theme}
          style={props.settings && props.settings["paper"]}
        >
          {props.showCloseIcon && (
            <CloseButton
              theme={theme}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log("remove");
                props.onClose && props.onClose();
              }}
            >
              <CloseIcon theme={theme}></CloseIcon>
            </CloseButton>
          )}
          <div>{props.content}</div>
          <ButtonGroup>
            {props.onOK && (
              <Button
                theme={theme}
                onClick={props.onOK as any}
                style={props.settings && props.settings["okButton"]}
              >
                OK
              </Button>
            )}
            {props.onCancel && (
              <Button
                theme={theme}
                onClick={props.onCancel as any}
                style={props.settings && props.settings["cancelButton"]}
              >
                CANCEL
              </Button>
            )}
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Content>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Popup;
```

**App.tsx**
I call popup multiple times to test it

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openPopup, closePopup] = usePopup();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Text</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          openPopup({
            content: <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>0</div>,
            showCloseIcon: true,
            disableBackdropClick: true,
            onOK: () => {
              openPopup({
                content: <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>1</div>,
                showCloseIcon: true,
                disableBackdropClick: true,
                onOK: () =>
                  openPopup({
                    content: <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>2</div>,
                    showCloseIcon: true,
                    disableBackdropClick: true,
                    onOK: () => {
                      openPopup({
                        content: <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>3</div>,
                        showCloseIcon: true,
                        disableBackdropClick: true,
                        onOK: () => {},
                        onCancel: closePopup,
                        theme: "light",
                      });
                    },
                    onCancel: closePopup,
                    theme: "dark",
                  }),
                onCancel: closePopup,
              });
            },
            onCancel: closePopup,
            theme: "dark",
            settings: settings,
          });
        }}
      >
        open modal
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: popups.pop() mutates state and is probably causing your bug

Comment: i change it to use prevState as asynchrous away in setPopups. But it didn't work. i use .pop() to remove the last item in the list. from 4 to 3. but some how only 2 were rendered.